# There are 2 Log.i statements in the script. Only the 2nd one shows up

Tags: android

here is the code snippet

```
    Log.i("poweruptcoach:aboutx000",MainActivity.pathtocoach);
    if(MainActivity.pathtocoach != null && !MainActivity.pathtocoach.isEmpty()){
        filespec = ServerFileSpec + MainActivity.pathtocoach;
    }
    topstuff = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.topstuff);
    Button coachesBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.coachesBtn);
    Button disclaimerBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.disclaimerBtn);
    Log.i("poweruptcoach:aboutx00","?" +MainActivity.pathtocoach+"?");
```

The first log-aboutx000, does not appear in catlog, but the second one-aboutx00, does. WHY?

Comment: If this is your actual code, it seems like it should work. However, if `MainActivity.pathtocoach` is `null`, your app will probably crash with a `NullPointerException`. Also, note that the log tag ("poweruptcoach:aboutx000") must be no longer than 23 characters.

Comment: @kabuko, if it were null, you'd get an exception and _neither_ log message would appear. As for the 23-char limit, it's right on the borderline, but still okay.

Comment: @paxdiablo Agreed on both points. They were just things I wanted to call out (which is why I didn't make my comment an answer instead). That's why I said "crash with a NullPointerException". And yes, 23 is right on the border but should be ok, but I figured I'd throw it out there in case the code in the post wasn't exactly the code that he's using. Wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since they're using different tags, that's the first thing I'd be checking.

It may be that you're filtering on the tagname. You can set properties to indicate at what log level each tag is allowed to log, and check this programatically with `isLoggable()`.

It should be easy to see if this is the case by simply changing the tag on the first one to match the second one, and seeing if it appears after that.

---

> Humorous aside: I've just noticed that the `Log` class contains a few `wtf()` methods, supposedly for "What a terrible failure". That's not a very believable acronym, it's similar to Alex's renaming of "The Daily WTF" to mean "worse than failure" - I think we *all* know what this really stands for :-)